# Так же как и - With or without comma?

Tags: грамматика, пунктуация

In the following sentence:

> Я встал 8 часов утро, так же как и всегда.

Do I have to place a comma between **так же** and **как и**?

Would the meaning drastically change if instead, I said the following? (Because to me, it's identical)

> Я встал 8 часов утро, как всегда.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a comma [isn't needed](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_710) between **так же** and **как и** in this case.

BTW: The part before the comma should be written as:

> Я встал **в** 8 часов утр**а**, ...

For me, the most common way to express this is:

> Я, как всегда, встал в 8 часов утра.

Putting *как всегда* at the end of the sentence makes me think that you want to stress that you **always** wake up at 8. If you write **так же как и всегда** you make the emphasis stronger.

---

##### Update

There are two options. Whether a comma is needed or not depends on what **так же(,) как и** is. If it's a **conjunction**, it isn't necessary. In this case, it's synonymous with **как**. When it's an **adverb + particle + conjunction**, a comma is necessary.

So, how do you distinguish between these two cases?

If **так же(,) как и** expresses that the situation as a whole before **так же...** is the same as after it, then **так же как и** is a **conjunction** and no comma is necessary.

> В детстве я проводил лето на даче, так же как и большинство моих одноклассников.

What's expressed here is that my situation, *Я проводил лето на даче* (I spent the summer at my dacha), is the same as my classmates' situation (they also spent the summer at their dachas).

If you compare the way of doing something, then it's an **adverb + particle + conjunction** and you need a comma.

> Он старался плавать так же, как и остальные ребята в бассейне

Here, **так** is an adverb describing the way he swam: the same as other boys did. So, everything after "так же, как и" is a description of how he swam.

So, if **так** describes the whole clause, then the construction **"так же как и"** is a **conjunction** and a comma inside isn't necessary (in this case the comma should be before it). If **так** describes a verb, then it's an **"adverb + particle + conjunction"** and you need a comma inside (but not before).

In your sentence, you compare the whole situation, **I woke up at 8 o'clock**, with the same situation repeated day after day. That makes **так же как и** a conjunction.

Comment: Sorry, my Russian is too bad for the link you have provided. And Google Translater outputs stuff I don't understand unfortunately. Because user Amanbolat Balabekov said the exact opposit from you answer I not sure who is right in this case.

Comment: Actually @Amanbolat Balabekov gave a wrong explanation, his link go to the explanation of the difference between **также** and **так же** and I haven't enough reputation to comment his answer. So the point is: when **так же как и** is a **conjunction**, a comma isn't needed. When it is **adverb + particle + conjunction** a comma is necessary. In your sentence, it is obviously conjunction. Sorry, I'll add explanation into my answer later.

Answer (score 1):

> Так же, как и

There should be a comma.

There are a lot of examples:
http://pishempravilno.ru/takzhe-i-tak-zhe/

Comment: Sorry, my Russian is too bad for the link you have provided. And Google Translater outputs stuff I don't understand unfortunately. Because user Vitaly said the exact opposit from you answer I not sure who is right in this case.

Comment: Your link mostly about difference between **также** and **так же** it is not quit fit the situation.

Comment: @SilvingsQuantu Don't use Google Translate. Use DeepL for better chances of a natural translation: deepl.com